# Custom object tab list fields do not link to object detail

Tags: custom-object, list-view, tab, list

> Hey guys,

I hope I'm not asking this question twice - I though I asked earlier, but now that I look at my profile, I don't see it.

Anyhow, I created a custom object. On the custom tab, when I pull a list of the custom objects, none of the fields in the list/report link to the object detail. For standard objects, when I pull a list on the tab (say Leads tab), each field on the list (name, phone, whatever) links to the object detail. My custom tab doesn't behave this way. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For custom objects, the "Name" field is presented as a link to the object detail but simple attributes such as text fields, numbers, checkboxes etc are not. So make sure that you include the "Name" field.

Also relationship fields such as lookup fields are presented as a link to the related object.

Comment: Thanks! I was mainly confused as the only documentation I found was that the list view on custom tabs should behave the way it does for standard objects, which in this case isn't true. It's not a hindrance to workflow as the Name field does indeed still link.